# Property x does not exist on type react

Tags: reactjs

I am not sure why I am getting this error
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Portal | undefined'

Here is my code:

```
export interface Portal {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  announcement?: Announcment;
  //highlights: Highlight[];
  highlightGroupResults?: HighlightGroup[];
  helpfulTips?: HelpfulTip[];
  categories: Category[];
  helpMessage?: string;
  contact: Contact;
}
```

```
 const [portal, setPortal] = useState<Portal>();

const{
    name //where I get the error
  } = portal
```

Comment: Your initial state is `undefined`, which does not have a `name` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the initial state when use `useState`.

```
const [portal, setPortal] = useState<Portal>({id: "",name: "",contact: null});
```